# filtering pandas timedelta with 2 filters - greater than and less than certain amount of time

Tags: python, pandas, timedelta

I m filtering this dataframe and need to filter out the data thats between 2 and 5 days. for some reason the '&' operator is giving me errors. when i do it separately works but when i do them together it gives me an error. here is what i did

```
between2_and_5_days =  dis_weekly[dis_weekly['time_delta']<= '5 days 00:00:00.000000']&dis_weekly[dis_weekly['time_delta'] >'2 days 00:00:00.000000']
```

and then i get

> 'TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'float' and 'float'

Comment: `between2_and_5_days =  dis_weekly[(dis_weekly['time_delta']<= '5 days 00:00:00.000000') & (dis_weekly['time_delta'] >'2 days 00:00:00.000000')]`

Comment: the `&` operator is between two DataFrames, which wouldn't work

Comment: You have to put your conditions into tuples ``(`` ``)``, like @aydow did.